# How can I increment value if condition matches by Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am newbie about redux. I want to increment state by one when condition matches. Condition is true, i checked on the console. This is action;

```
if(btn.target.value == answer) {
            dispatch(calculate(prev => prev +1))
}
```

This is state;

```
export const scoreSlice = createSlice({
name: "score",
initialState: {value: 0}, 
reducers: {
    calculate: (state,action) => {
        state.value = action.payload
    }
}
```

output on the console;

```
prev => prev + 1
```

Comment: A few questions. What is your issue with what you have? Just from looking at what you posted, I see the `calculate` reducer is a little strange. You shouldn't set the state, but copy and return a mutated state. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#reducers-and-immutable-updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you dispatch action, pass the number that you want to add to your value

```js
if (btn.target.value == answer) {
  dispatch(calculate(1))
}
```

in reducer function => action.payload represents anything you pass to this function while dispatching it (action.payload = 1 here)

```js
const reducers = {
  calculate: (state, action) => ({
    ...state, // copy original state
    value: state.value + action.payload
  })
}
```

Comment: Please ensure your code snippets are *runnable* as they are, otherwise just use a code block instead.